# How to merge or remap columns with the same name?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I would like to merge two columns if they have the same column name. I would like the value of the duplicate column to replace the NaN value.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
 PETS    PETS   FRUITS  COUNTRY  FRUITS
 Pig     NaN    Apple   USA      NaN
 Cat     NaN     NaN    NL       Banana
 NaN     Dog     NaN    NaN      NaN
```

This is what I would my datafame to look like:

```
PETS   FRUITS   COUNTRY
Pig     Apple    USA
Cat     Banana    NL
Dog     NaN      NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `groupby` `first` method returns the first non-null value.

```
df.groupby(df.columns, 1).first()

  COUNTRY  FRUITS PETS
0     USA   Apple  Pig
1      NL  Banana  Cat
2     NaN     NaN  Dog
```

---

Without sorting

```
df.groupby(df.columns, 1, sort=False).first()

  PETS  FRUITS COUNTRY
0  Pig   Apple     USA
1  Cat  Banana      NL
2  Dog     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Far better than mine, this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 4):

You can group by columns and use `ffill` followed by `pd.concat`:

```
g = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1)
res = pd.concat([sub.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, -1] for _, sub in g], axis=1)

print(res)

  COUNTRY  FRUITS PETS
0     USA   Apple  Pig
1      NL  Banana  Cat
2     NaN     NaN  Dog
```